# CSS Rules Involving the Value of data-* In Ancestors Not Working Well With IE When Value of data-* Is Changed

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

@Duplicate Flag: The problem is similar as that old question, but not the same. For starters, his problem was with IE 8 and resolved in IE 9, 10 and 11. Mine was with IE 10 & 11.

I have a barebone proof of concept page below to show what I'm talking about.

Basically, I'm trying to use HTML5 data-* attributes to augment the semantic meaning of my page and use css rules to style display instead of using show/hide logic with javaScript.

The code below works well in Firefox/Chrome, but fails in Internet Explorer 10 and 11.

I guess I could use classes in the parent instead to get a similar behavior, but HTML5 attributes seem even better suited for this and that I can't get them to work with IE bugs me.

Any insights?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            .Container[data-Verbose="Yes"] .NotVerbose
            {
                display: none;
            }
            .Container[data-Verbose="No"] .Verbose
            {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="Container" data-Verbose="Yes">
            <a class="Verbose">Not Verbose Please</a>
            <a class="NotVerbose">Verbose Please</a>
            <p class="Verbose">*Long Paragraph*</p>
            <p class="NotVerbose">*Short Sentence*</p>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).on('click', '.Container a', function(Event) {
                var Target = jQuery(this);
                console.log(Target);
                if(Target.is('.Verbose'))
                {
                    jQuery('.Container').attr('data-Verbose', 'No');
                }
                else if(Target.is('.NotVerbose'))
                {
                    jQuery('.Container').attr('data-Verbose', 'Yes');
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [working](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1gxat6mc/1/) vs [not working](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1gxat6mc/2/) - so it is the same problem with the redraw not being initialized by change in a `data-*` attribute

Comment: It seems you are right. It is the same underlying problem.

However, your answer is better, because the class changes seem to force a redraw all the time, while the opacity change in the other question only forces a re-draw the first time.

Furthermore, they imply in the other question that the problem is fixed with IE9+ which is only partially true. The problem that was caused by the implementation in the other question is fixed in IE9+, but the problem that is caused by my implementation remains.

As such, I believe the info presented here is a necessary supplement to that other post.

Comment: you can simplify it to http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1gxat6mc/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played with the "document mode" of IE in the console and the example above only behaves properly in IE 9 (but not other versions). It's also worth mentioning that even IE 9 misbehaves with a more complex set of CSS rules that use data-* attributes so putting the following in your head to force IE to behave like IE 9 may work in certain cases, but is NOT a robust workaround:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

The problem, as outlined by others before me, is that IE doesn't redraw properly in some cases when data-* are changed, a problem that was reported in IE 8 and still seems to be present in later version with more complicated css rules.

A solution that was outlined before is to change the style to some default value (ie, an opacity of 1) of the affected elements to force a redraw, but it appears that optimizations in later versions of IE won't re-draw when style properties are reset to the same value making the above solution untenable unless you can find a css property that has 2 different values that won't affect your display.

A more reliable solution to always force a re-draw is to add and remove an arbitrary class on elements whose data-* attributes are modified.

A convenient wrapper for the setter of jQuery.attr that fixes this can be found here:

https://github.com/Magnitus-/IEAttrWorkaround